# Print Char array using pointers in c

Tags: c, string, pointers

When i see the ourput of the following code, i am getting "hello123 hello123 hello123".

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        char arr[4][2][3] = {'h','e','l','l','0','1','2','3'};
        printf("%s ", arr);
        printf("%s ", *arr);
        printf("%s ", **arr);
        return 0;
}
```

Can anyone help me with the answer?

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior of the code you have posted is **undefined**. Your compiler should give warnings:

In function 'main':

```
    5   9   [Warning] missing braces around initializer [-Wmissing-braces]
    5   9   [Warning] (near initialization for 'arr[0]') [-Wmissing-braces]
    6   9   [Warning] format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char (*)[2][3]' [-Wformat]
    7   9   [Warning] format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char (*)[3]' [-Wformat]
```

Using wrong specifier to print data types invokes undefined behavior.

---

The possible reason for the output is that all of `arr`, `*arr` and `**arr` pointing to the same starting address (but all are of different types), so `printf` with `%s` specifier start reading characters from that address and stops at `\0` and prints the same output in all cases.
Note that, since initializer is used, so the rest of the array elements initialized to `\0` by default.

Comment: More info: when the initializers are not braced, they just apply to cells in row-major order; so index 000=h, 001=e, 002=l, 010=l, 011=0, 012=1, 100=2, 101=3, all others null. The `printf` calls read off the end of `arr[0][0]` (causing UB even in the last case) but since the array is contiguous and your compiler isn't doing bounds checking, it reads the next row.